# Using enum in ES2015

Tags: javascript, enums, ecmascript-6

How do I use enums in ES2015? I tried the following but I'm getting errors:

Created a file for my enums i.e. errorTypes.js

```
export const Types = {
   MISSING_DATA: 0,
   INVALID_DATA: 1
}
```

I then tried to import this into my React component and use it as follows:

```
import errorTypes from '../enums/errorTypes';

handleOnClick(event) {

   // Some logic here
   const newError = {type: errorTypes.INVALID_DATA, message: "Please type carefully!"};

}
```

The error I'm getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'INVALID_DATA' of undefined

Comment: `Types` != `errorTypes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not importing or exporting the data correctly. You are getting the error because you are trying to import the default export from the module, but since module doesn't have a default export, `errorTypes` ends up being `undefined`.

Either use a default export:

```
export default {
  MISSING_DATA: 0,
  INVALID_DATA: 1,
};
```

Or use a named import:

```
import {Types} from '...';
```

---

Learn more about [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) on MDN.